How to update a matching record with a flow?
So I have a Custom record Object1, that has a lookup Assigned User to a user, has an Active checkbox and Opportunity has a lookup on that object. When I create/update an instance of Object1 so that its Active=True, I need to check the opportunities whos Owner is matching the Assigned User on the Object1. and, if the Stage of the Opportunity is correct, I need to assign this record to the Opportunity.
So, I created a record triggered flow, that checks if the records has Active=true, then I added a getRecord to get the opportunities, where Opportunity.OwnerID=TriggeredRecord.AssignedUserID
And then I choose the Update Record element and I can't choose there to update fields on the Opportunities I have gotten in the GetRecord.

So, what am I doing wrong? can I assign the newly created record to an opportunity I need with a flow?

The Get Record element is most likely returning a collection (1+) Opportunity. You need to loop through these to set the field(s)

I think you are missing the Loop Through the Opportunities and an Assignment element to set the lookup field on the opportunity to the newly created or updated Object1 record.
After getting all the opportunities, make sure to store all the records in a collection variable ( that you already did).
Now,

Add a Loop element to iterate through the collection of
opportunities.
Inside the loop, use an Assignment element to set the lookup field on
the opportunity to the newly created or updated Object1 record.
Add each updated opportunity to another collection variable.
After the loop, use an Update Records element to update the
opportunities with the new values from the collection variable.


Thanks! will try that.

Yes, it totally worked!

@SlavaBychenkoCT, I am glad it worked for you. Please mark the answer as accepted so it helps others in the future as well. Thanks.
